# Buildozer built apk not working

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

For about 2 days from now I am trying to compile a simple Hello World app using `Buildozer`. I've tried it on several computers and it didn't work on any of them. I tried to do the simplest way possible to find out the problem, but I couldn't and it is getting really annoying now.

I have `Elementary OS` on my laptop, but I've tried with `Debian` as well.

Here is my main.py:

```
__version__ = “1.0”
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Hello(App):
    def build(self):
        btn = Button(text='Hello World')
        return  btn

Hello().run()
```

Here's the logcat log when running the app:

```
02-17 11:08:42.030: E/dalvikvm(6666): dlopen("/data/data/org.testapp.testapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.testapp.testapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
02-17 11:08:42.030: E/dalvikvm(6666): dlopen("/data/data/org.testapp.testapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.testapp.testapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
```

I've included `sqlite3` in requirements (though I don't think it should be necessary in a simple app like above), but the message is the same.

I've tried it on several `Android devices`, but all of them throws this error.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Here's my buildozer.spec:

```
[app]
title = TestApp
package.name = testapp
package.domain = org.testapp
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,kv
version = 0.1
# buildozer init only put kivy, I've added sqlite3 later, to see if it solves the problem, but the issue is the same
requirements = sqlite3,kivy
orientation = landscape
fullscreen = 1
android.api = 19
android.sdk = 19
android.sdk_path = /home/zslevi/Android/Sdk/
[buildozer]
log_level = 1
warn_on_root = 1
```

EDIT #2:

Here's the full log: [Full log](http://lime.cf/adblog.txt)

EDIT #3:

I've seen an INFO notice that it can't find main.py/main.pyo, but here's my folder: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA8fk.png)

Comment: I remember having a lot of problems aswell at creating my first simple apk file. Post your android.spec file (but delete commented lines), and also make sure you have installed all dependencies from installation guide.

Comment: @przyczajony I've included now, everything is installed (as far as I know sqlite3 comes default with python 2.7).

Comment: Try deleting `android.sdk`, `android.sdk_path` and that `sqlite3`.

Comment: The sqlite errors are just warnings. Could you post the full logcat?

Comment: It is the same, originally those lines were commented too, later I've tried to include them, but the issue is the same. I've got a freshly installed laptop, latest version of kivy, python and buildozer, but using that throws the same issue (with the original buildozer.spec, no `android.sdk` `android.sdk_path`, and `sqlite3`.

Comment: @inclement I'll include, and they're errors not warnings.

Comment: My last ideas: 1) uninstall app from phone, 2) delete bin and hidden .buildozer catalog, 3) exclude the lines from buildozer.spec I wrote previously, 4) install again with `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat` (without sudo).

Comment: @przyczajony same thing :/ I've tried on samsung galaxy tab s, galaxy s4, xiaomi mi4, on at least 5 marsboards... no luck, got the same error always.

Comment: You could also try deleting the version in main.py file, as it serves no purpose and also differs in spec file. Try also changing package name and domain.

Answer (score 0):

An old issue, but still relevant since I just installed a fresh qemu install of ubuntu 16, the latest kivy and got this issue running Hello World (using android V4.4)

My problem was simply that I had named my python app "hello_world.py" instead of "main.py".

Renaming it to "main.py" and recompiling made it work for me.